# Issues with making images draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, exit

I am currently creating my own website. I need code to allow users to change the position of some images by dragging them. I have written this HTML, CSS and JS in separate files.

The whole click and drag think works, when I click on the image and drag it on any side, it moves.

When I release the mouse button nothing happens. I have tried `break` and `return`, but they don't stop the function. Do you have any suggestions?

PS: I'm only a beginner in JS, so if you have any other advice about my code, go for it!

```js
class img {
  constructor(id, left, top) {
    this.id = "#" + id;
    this.left = parseInt(left, 10);
    this.top = parseInt(top, 10);
  };
};

$(".draggable").on("mousedown", function detectClick(focus) {
  var stop = false;
  var clickPos = [focus.pageX, focus.pageY];
  var selected = new img($(this).attr('id'), $(this).css("left"), $(this).css("top"));
  console.log(clickPos, selected);
  $(selected.id).on("mousemove", function startMvt(move) {
    var newPos = [move.pageX, move.pageY];
    console.log(newPos);
    $(selected.id).css("top", selected.top + newPos[1] - clickPos[1]);
    $(selected.id).css("left", selected.left + newPos[0] - clickPos[0]);
    $(selected.id).on("mouseup", function stop() {
      var stop = true
      console.log("stopped moving!");
      return;
    });
    if (stop) {
      return false;
    };
  });
  if (stop) {
    return false;
  };
}).delay(5);
```

```css
.draggable {
  position: relative;
}

#img_1 {
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="draggable" id="img_1" draggable="false" src="content/medium_im_test.jpg">
```

Comment: A common way to implement a click-drag-drop is to listen mousedown on the element, then when that fires, attach mousemove and mouseup to `document`. When mouseup fires, mousemove and mouseup events are detached.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".draggable").on("mousedown",`

you are only calling a function on the event of mousedown, you need a corresponding [mouseup](https://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) event handler.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding

```
    .mouseup(function(){
        alert('up');
    });
```

at the end or .delay(5);

like

```
        $(".draggable").on("mousedown", function detectClick(focus) {
            var stop = false;
            var clickPos = [focus.pageX, focus.pageY];
            var selected = new img($(this).attr('id'), $(this).css("left"), $(this).css("top"));
            console.log(clickPos, selected);
            $(selected.id).on("mousemove", function startMvt(move) {
                var newPos = [move.pageX, move.pageY];
                console.log(newPos);
                $(selected.id).css("top", selected.top + newPos[1] - clickPos[1]);
                $(selected.id).css("left", selected.left + newPos[0] - clickPos[0]);
                $(selected.id).on("mouseup", function stop() {
                var stop = true
                console.log("stopped moving!");
                return;
                });
                if (stop) {
                return false;
                };
            });
        if (stop) {
            return false;
        };
        }).delay(5).mouseup(function(){
            alert('up');
        });
```

it worked for me!! I am also a beginner js programmer! so I don't fully understand your code, but I think you have to do something where I put `alert('up')`